# Normal email address can't be resolved when using python smtplib to send email via office365

Tags: python, office365, smtplib

I'm trying to send email using python, and here's my code basically:

```
mail_host = MAIL_HOST
mail_user = MAIL_USER
mail_pass = MAIL_PASS
mail_postfix = MAIL_POSTFIX
self.server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_host, port=MAIL_PORT)
self.server.ehlo()
self.server.starttls()
self.server.login(mail_user + "@" + mail_postfix, mail_pass)
self.my_name = MAIL_DISPLAY_SENDER
self.my_addr = self.my_name+"<"+mail_user+"@"+mail_postfix+">"
self.server.sendmail(self.my_addr, "liping.zhang@cimc.com", message.as_string())
```

Then I got this error:

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidRecipientsException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Recipient "liping.zhang@cimc.com" isn\'t resolved. All recipients must be resolved before a message can be submitted. InvalidRecipientsException: Recipient "liping.zhang@cimc.com" isn\'t resolved. All recipients must be resolved before a message can be submitted. [Hostname=HK2PR01MB3123.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com]')
```

What happened here? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I met the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: @ZRHan I didn't. I used `emails` instead of `smtplib` and it worked.

Comment: Ok thank you! I also abandoned `smtplib` and used `yagmail`.

Answer (score -1):

Try Changing  The Subject Line Of The Message to Be Sent.
Also If you sent too many emails in a single day then try
sending another day.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.